# File Output in Powershell without Extension

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Here is what I have so far:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder" | Foreach-Object {$_.Name} > C:\Folder\File.txt
```

When you open the output from above, File.txt, you see this:

```
file1.txt
file2.mpg
file3.avi
file4.txt
```

How do I get the output so it drops the extension and only shows this:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

Thanks in advance!

***EDIT***

Figured it out with the help of the fellows below me. I ended up using:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder" | Foreach-Object {$_.BaseName} > C:\Folder\File.txt
```

Comment: since I was looking for something a little different and Google landed me here: If someone is trying to only _get_ files that don't have an extension, try `Get-ChildItem $dir | ? {$_.Extension -ne ""}`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder" | Select BaseName > C:\Folder\File.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reminder. I could not remember BaseName for the life of me. I ended up using: Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder" | Foreach-Object {$_.BaseName} > C:\Folder\File.txt

Comment: @CaptHowdy `$foo | Get-Member` will reveal the properties and methods of an object.

Comment: If someone is looking for the shorthand version for current directory, try this `ls . | Select BaseName`.

Comment: I wish I could fave @ansgar-wiechers' comment, I always seem to forget about Get-Member!

Answer (score 4):

Pass the file name to the [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) to remove the extension:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder" | `
    ForEach-Object { [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name) } `
    > C:\Folder\File.txt
```

---

I wanted to comment on [@MatthewMartin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13370345/150605), which splits the incoming file name on the `.` character and returns the first element of the resulting array.  This will work for names with zero or one `.`, but produces incorrect results for anything else:

- `file.ext1.ext2` yields `file`
- `powershell.exe is good for me. Let me explain to thee..doc` yields `powershell`

The reason is because it's returning everything before the *first* `.` when it should really be everything before the *last* `.`.  To fix this, once we have the name split into segments separated by `.`, we take every segment except the last and join them back together separated by `.`.  In the case where the name does not contain a `.` we return the entire name.

```
ForEach-Object {
    $segments = $_.Name.Split('.')

    if ($segments.Length -gt 1) {
        $segmentsExceptLast = $segments | Select-Object -First ($segments.Length - 1)

        return $segmentsExceptLast -join '.'
    } else {
        return $_.Name
    }
}
```

A more efficient approach would be to walk backwards through the name character-by-character.  If the current character is a `.`, return the name up to but not including the current character.  If no `.` is found, return the entire name.

```
ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_.Name;

    for ($i = $name.Length - 1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
        if ($name[$i] -eq '.') {
            return $name.Substring(0, $i)
        }
    }

    return $name
}
```

The [`[String]` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string) already provides [a method to do this same thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof), so the above can be reduced to...

```
ForEach-Object {
    $i = $_.Name.LastIndexOf([Char] '.');

    if ($i -lt 0) {
        return $_.Name
    } else {
        return $_.Name.Substring(0, $i)
    }
}
```

All three of these approaches will work for names with zero, one, or multiple `.` characters, but, of course, they're a lot more verbose than the other answers, too.  In fact, `LastIndexOf()` is [what `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` uses internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,e36b3edc1f3e2c8d), while [what `BaseName` uses](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/ceed73d7375cb98a199ceb19796bb2311b0b0002/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/Types_Ps1Xml.cs#L210) is functionally the same as calling [`$_.Name.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) except it takes advantage of the [already-computed extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension).

Answer (score 3):

And now for a FileInfo version, since everyone else beat me to a Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension solution.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\" | `
where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | `
Foreach-Object {([System.IO.FileInfo]($_.Name)).Name.Split('.')[0]}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, files I had also had some numbers appended to it. having .split('.') helped me cut off everything that was appended including ext.

Comment: It should be noted that removing an extension involves returning everything before the _last_ `.` whereas this will return everything before the _first_ `.`. For names that contain zero or one `.` (such as in the question) there is no difference, but for names like `file.ext1.ext2` and `powershell.exe is good for me. Let me explain to thee..doc` it returns `file` and `powershell`, respectively. I have updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13370130/150605) with a few approaches to fix this. By the way, `[System.IO.FileInfo]($_.Name)).Name` is redundant and can be reduced to `$_.Name`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(ls).BaseName > C:\Folder\File.txt
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use the BaseName property instead of the Name property:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Folder" | Select-Object BaseName > C:\Folder\File.txt
```

Comment: you should probably explain why:  Basename gives file name without extension.  Name property contains extension.